# Object instance type checking from another file

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-decorators, python-packaging, modular-design

I have modularized my python code into three files. **File1.py** has a class definition with its methods and attributes defined inside of the class. **File2.py** serves as a layer between the input that comes to the program and then calls the methods and operates on those inputs, basically acting as an interface. While **File3.py** I made it for sanity check for inputs. I am decorating the relevant methods of the class with some sanity-check decorators defined in **File3.py**. One such decorator has python's `isinstance(input_received, class_name)`. Now, since checking is happening in **File3**, class is defined in **File1**, the decorator is taking only class method as an input, where input(class) method has `(self, input_received)`, my `isinstance(input_received, class_name)` statement is throwing an error that `"'class_name' is unknown"`, which means class_name definition is not in **File3**'s scope.
I've imported File3 in File1, and File1 in File2.
Also, cyclic importing is not an option. It'll be a dumb thing to do. I mean, importing File3 in File1 in addition to all the existing imports.

Please help!

**File1 (arith.py)**

```
import decors # importing the decorator for input sanity check

class Coords(object):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.abscissa = x
        self.ordinate = y

    def __add__(self, other):
        """ Normal left operand addition """
        return Coords(self.abscissa + other.abscissa, self.ordinate + other.ordinate)

    def __neg__(self):
        """ Negation """
        return Coords(-self.abscissa, -self.ordinate)

    @decors.neg_san_check # decorating __sub__ method
    def __sub__(self, other):
        """ Normal left operand subtraction """
        return self + other.__neg__()
```

**File3 (decors.py)**

```
from functools import wraps

def neg_san_check(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def wrapper(obj_ref, other_obj):
          if isinstance(other_obj, (Coords, int, float)):
                func(obj_ref, other_obj)
    return wrapper
```

**File2 (base.py)**

```
from arith import Coords

c1 = Coords(3,6)
c2 = Coords(7,8)

diff = c1-c2
print(diff.abscissa)
print(diff.ordinate)
```

**Here's an error:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "base.py", line 6, in <module>
    diff = c1-c2
  File "/home/somepath/codedir/decors.py", line 6, in wrapper
    if isinstance(other_obj, (Coords, int, float)):
NameError: name 'Coords' is not defined
```

**Note:** All 3 files lies in *codedir* directory

Comment: You *must* provide a [mcve]

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I've edited my post provided MRE as per your request. I tried to reproduce a similar scenario, but not exactly the same (since the original codebase is too large). Hope you'll find it useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After struggling through many websites, here I came up the solution for **File3 (decors.py)**

```
from functools import wraps

def neg_san_check(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def wrapper(obj_ref, other_obj):
          if isinstance(other_obj, (obj_ref.__class__, int, float)):
                func(obj_ref, other_obj)
```

I would also like to add one more scenario:
Suppose if we have assure that the passed instance(other_obj) is of type some other class (which is different from 'obj_ref.**class**', then we can pass that OTHER CLASS's class variable (whose sole purpose is to use for type checking out of its own class) to the function which is decorated in the current class.

Answer (score 0):

`decors.py` does not import `Coords` and therefore the line `if isinstance(other_obj, (Coords, int, float))` throw the exception.
Moving the decorator to `arith.py` should solve the problem.

Comment: But I've imported decors.py in arith.py already. Wouldn't it be cyclic import, two files into each other?
Or, am I doing it in wrong way?

Comment: @saint_sharan why dont you have the decorator and `Coords` in the same py module? After all the decorator is dedicated to `Coords` - isnt it?

Comment: because, I have modularize my code base. Every file serves different purpose

Comment: but since the decorator is "tailored" to `Coords` there is no point to have it in a other module. There is no added value in doing it.

Comment: As I mentioned, I have not mentioned my complete code. Its just a stimulation of my my real code, which is doing type checking for many other class.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could provide me solution for this specific scenario. The problem is not about the solution which you are suggesting. Its about type checking of class object from different file using decorators.

Comment: try to add the import to  `Coords` after `def neg_san_check(func):` - it should work

Comment: Hey, I have already mentioned that it will create ImportError due to cyclic importing. Also, now that I have provided the file codes, I expect that you will try to create similar scenario and try to look for valid solution, instead of just making castle in the air.